# Clean way to import standard libraries while importing a file in another script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am trying to import a module in another python script but I am getting an error in loading the standard python library even after declaring it explicitly.
If I am not using any standard library in the actual file then I can import it in the below way without any hassle.
Both the files are in the same folder -

On importing the python file `dataset.py` below in the following way -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dataset import split_equal_into_val_test
```

I am getting `NameError: name 'train_test_split' is not defined`

My dataset file looks like below -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_equal_into_val_test(X=df, y = df['y']):

    df_train, df_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X,y)
    
    return df_train,df_temp,y_train, y_temp
```

Edit:
I just solved this problem the below way but still have a doubt -
I imported the complete library inbuilt function inside the function which is getting imported like this `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,y)` but it doesn't look a very clean idea to me as I have to refactor my entire code base in this way. Is there any other way?

Comment: I solved it by importing the complete library inside the function which is getting imported like this `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,y)` but it doesn't look a very clean idea to me as I have to refactor my entire code base in this way. Is there any other way?

Comment: sounds like a typo? what happens if you run a linter such as flake8 against the old file?

Comment: Woah, I never knew the purpose of linter or code formatting. Though, I still don't know what the error was but I removed the warnings of linter and it got resolved. A lot to learn for me. Thanks.